# How many irreducible representations of $GL(d,\mathbb{R})$ are contained in a rank $(n,0)$ tensor?

Tags: representation-theory, tensors

Given a rank $(n,0)$ tensor $\varphi^{\mu_1\dots\mu_n}$ which transforms under $GL(d,\mathbb{R})$ like
$$\varphi^{\mu_1\dots\mu_n}\to M^{\mu_1}_{\;\;\nu_1}\cdots M^{\mu_n}_{\;\;\nu_n}\varphi^{\nu_1\dots\nu_n},\quad M\in GL(d,\mathbb{R})$$
I would like to understand the type of irreducible representations in such a tensor. Symmetry and antisymmetry of indices is preserved under such a transformation, but I am struggling with the combinatorics to figure out all of the unique combinations of symmetry and antisymmetry of indices beyond rank $(2,0)$ tensors.

Comment: The irreducible summands of $(\mathbb{R}^{d})^{\otimes n}$ are given by Schur Functors (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor). In this context, Schur-Weyl duality says that the number of such total irreducible subrepresentations is given by the number of Young diagrams of size $n$ with length less than $d$.

Comment: ...and the multiplicity of such an irreducible corresponding to a diagram given by a partition $\lambda$ of $n$ with at most $d$ parts is the number of standard Young tableaux with that shape. See the book on representation theory by Fulton and Harris equation A.9 from Appendix A. The number of such standard tableaux is given by the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula